# Sending data to Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

A part of my website whose URL pattern starts with a fixed string **manage** eg: 'example.com/manage/post', 'example.com/manage/user' requires that certain information associated with the user is displayed on every page that belongs to this section of the website.

Do I have to return this information inside every view method to do so?

This information is not maintained in the User profile. It is maintained in a model outside the User Profile. There is a many to one relationship from this model to the User profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the user viewing the page? If so, just add the following to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your `settings.py`.

```
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'
```

This will give you access to the current user as a variable called `user` in all your templates.

Comment: This information is not maintained in the User profile. It is maintained in a model outside the User Profile. There is a many to one relationship from this model to the User profile.

Comment: You can access related models in templates just like you would in Python. For example, if the foreign key on your model is named `foo`, then you can access it in your template via `user.foo_set.all` (assuming you haven't specified `related_name`).

Comment: This seems to work in the shell. How can I work with it in a template?

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)